# Unable to push to GitLab endpoint LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, gitlab, libgit2sharp

I am attempting to initialize and push an initial commit to GitLab repository using LibGit2Sharp.

```
if (!Directory.Exists("D:\\GitRepos\\" + repositoryName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\GitRepos\\" + repositoryName);
            File.Create("D:\\GitRepos\\" + repositoryName + "\\README.md").Close();
        }

        Repository.Init("D:\\GitRepos\\" + repositoryName);

        using (var repo = new Repository("D:\\GitRepos\\" + repositoryName))
        {
            repo.Index.Add("README.md");
            Signature author = new Signature("user", "user@user.com", DateTime.Now);
            Signature committer = author;
            repo.Commit("Initial Commit", author, committer);
            repo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", validRepoHttpsUrl);
            Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];

            var options = new PushOptions
            {
                CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) =>
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials {Username = "validuser", Password = "validpassword"}
            };

            string pushRefSpec = @"refs/heads/master";
            repo.Network.Push(remote, pushRefSpec, options);

        }

}
```

The repository is created and initialized locally without issue. The README file is created and added to the repo index and commit succeeds. When I try to push the commit to the remote endpoint I receive an error stating :

```
"Request failed with status code: 411"
```

If I put a breakpoint right before the push and set the http.postBuffer for the repo with the following command:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

I receive a new error when the push executes:

```
Failed to write chunk footer: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
```

I was able to quickly stand up a bitbucket git repo and push to it without any issues, seems that this may be a problem with gitlab.

Comment: 411 is "Length Required".  Does GitLab not support chunked encoding?  Are you doubly certain that the URL is correct?  Can you push if you clone a repository - not try to push to a brand new repo?

Comment: (I'm not really sure how to answer that first question.  Paging GitLab CEO...)

Comment: If i put a break right before the push in code, I can call git push -u origin master on the command line and it works without issue.

Comment: We self-host gitlab and it works fine, but I just tried git:gitlab.com and https://gitlab.com and both fail. Found this open issue related to http error 411: push changes to a GitLab repo over HTTPS with credentials #905 : https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/905

Comment: I am also using self-hosted GitLab. I did see that error and tried the suggestions without any luck so far.

Comment: Not sure of your network/server/nginx config, but I would wireshark libgit2 vs git. Also look at your nginx logs for errors from the libgit2 connections.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I did attempt to push to a cloned repo and am getting the same error.

Comment: Your code fragment has "validRepoHttpUrl"  You are using https right?, not http: Also Self signed certs?

Comment: Yes https and my gitlab endpoint has a valid cert for my companies sub-domain.

Comment: The only other thing I add is, I am assuming you are running a newer ngnix and not one that had the chunkin module issue (1.3.? google it). There are .conf changes to fix that in those versions, but I would update to a 1.9.x version is possible

Comment: I was able to quickly stand up a bitbucket git repo and push to it without any issues, seems that this may be a problem with gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue for libgit2sharp based on RobertN's comment. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/905

I was able to work around this temporarily by handling the push with a git CLI call.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\\GitRepos\\" + repositoryName;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "git.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "push -u origin master";
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

Something to note is that when this is being run as a windows service as local system the call takes 2-3 minutes for a small commit to push. When i switched the service to run as a domain user it is immediate. Also, this only works because I have ssh and proper keys setup on my host, otherwise git would prompt for a username and password. I had to use the SSH URL instead of HTTP as stated in the original question.

Comment: :-) I do this all the time on Linux due to perf issues between libgit2/libgit2sharp and the official git releases (porcelain saves my bacon all the time on that)

Comment: If I only have to use the official git release for pushing I will still be happy, doing everything else in libgit2sharp is worth keeping it around in my mind.

Comment: Totally agree, it is way easier to deal with that way... But in my case, dealing have a custom libgit2 version hardwired to a EMC VNX Virtual file system but can not re-dist it due the GPL on it so I have to work around it at times. Just a sub-con job for me to maintain it while they write a new San-based VFS git lib that can actually be sold/sent to customers (something they never planned to do as it was for an internal use only system).

Comment: @RobertN That's very surprising.  Can you write up the issues you're seeing with libgit2 in an issue at https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2 so that we can investigate?